# Silent merge tool for git

Tags: git, merge, kdiff3

I have a build server set up to automatically keep a few products up to date with code from a "common" repository.

The build server merges in the common code, runs all tests and if OK it commits the results.

Everything is fine until there is merge conflicts in GIT. Sometimes there are "real conflicts" that require manual resolution but more often it can be auto resolved.

For example kdiff3 can resolve them automatically.

What I want is to be able to set up a mergetool so I can call "git mergetool" and if all could be auto resolved continue. If it cannot the process must exit. NO GUI can be shown since this is running in a build server process.

kdiff3 has a silent flag that disable the gui if conflicts could be resolved. But I need it to be disabled all the time.

To clarify. If conflict cannot be resolved automatically I want the build to fail and not open a gui.

Comment: I believe that Git pauses with merge conflicts because it deems that it cannot safely resolve such conflicts.  How would a merge tool do any better, and even if it could, the build could still fail in some cases.

Comment: Yes, but a merge tool DOES a  better job. For example kdiff 3 auto resolves it very often where git pauses. And If the build fails then the merged result does not end up being commited. The build fails. Just what I want. A hint to developer that manual attention is needed.

Comment: Fair enough point (upvote).  Maybe Git should improve its own merge abilities.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? You can set both Araxis and Beyond Compare to do what you want with the appropriate flags, but the problem is that if they fail "git mergetool" prompts: "Continue merging other unresolved paths?"

Comment: One approach could be to write a script that runs e.g. bcompare, always returns true as to not have git wait for your prompt, but sets some global flag (e.g. create FAILMERGE.txt) so that your CI system can understand a merge failure took place.

Comment: No I never found a solution that worked more or less "out of the box". I'm sure you can do it with custom scripts like you suggest etc. But I just don't have the time/energy to develop it from scratch.